# Portable java JAR and returning a file

Tags: java, csv

I have created Spring project which writes into a .csv file and then sends the file back to be downloaded from frontend. this works fine while testing at localhost. But when compiled to JAR the file paths change and result is `IOException file not found`

At the moment i have calculation.csv in my resources folder.

I also understand that i could write csv file outside of the JAR, but since this application needs to be portable and i have no guarantee of writing permissions, it makes this quite hard to accomplish.

is there a way, using maybe something like just input/output streams to make this work? **I have no need to save the file for longer times, i just need temp file to hold CSV information while it's being written** and then be able to return this same file to user (from endpoint).

current implimation is just a basic `File` which lives in resources/csv/calculation.csv

```
File file = new File("csv/calculation.csv");

Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(file);

transactionManagement.writeCSV(detailedList);
return response.build();
```

transactionManagement.writeCSV(detailedList);
is just a very simple service that writes csv line by line from data

Comment: Look at [Files.createTempFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-).

Comment: @vanje you wanna add that as answer? took less than hour with proper knowledge.. thanks